# Issue of numbers separators for the sending of grouped SMS on HTC

Tags: android, sms

There are several days that I look for a solution of my problem :

I develop an application which allows to send SMS.

So, if I wish to send a grouped SMS since a htc, it's impossible because the separator character has to be a semicolon (`;`). Thus if in my  Java code I replace my comma (`,`) by a semicolon (`;`) it works for the htc, but no more for others Androphones.

Have somebody any idea ? Knowing that I had thought of detecting the model of the androphone but it is impossible, no class exists below API LEVEL 12.  (I use API LEVEL 7 and  I don't have to change)

For more information see [usb device name](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getDeviceName%28%29).

*My JAVA code* :

```
for(int i = 0; i < listProches.size(); i++) {
  phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers + listProches.get(i).getTelephone()+";";  

   }

phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers.substring(0, phoneNumbers.lastIndexOf(";"));

Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumbers)); 
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", popupTexte);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution concerning my problem on htc. As I said to you, I tried to return how the MANUFACTURER of the androphone, and after detailed researches I found!!!

I give you the answer, and it works from API LEVEL 1 :

```
private  String  MANUFACTURER = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;  

if(MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("htc")){

telMobileproches += ";"; 
Log.v("MANUFACTURER", MANUFACTURER);
}

else{
telMobileproches += ",";
}
```

See more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, in your loop after the last phone number there is a semicolon.

do a check in your loop if the phonenumber is the last one in the list, if so do not add a semicolon to the end

```
for(int i = 0; i < listProches.size(); i++) {
  phoneNumbers += listProches.get(i).getTelephone();

  if(i != listProches.size()-1){
      phoneNumbers += ";";
  }

   }
```

code might be wrong... this is just an example

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but although my way to proceed is different from the one that you suggest me, my code works because I did :

**phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers.substring (0,phoneNumbers.lastIndexOf ("; "));**

Your code is more, and I keep it for this reason, however it doesn't resolve my problem which is for reminder :

   ***I wish to send a grouped SMS since a htc, but it's impossible because the separator character has to be a semicolon (;). Thus if in my Java code I replace my comma (,) by a semicolon (;) it works for the htc, but no more for others Androphones*.**

Thanks !